# Cordova Windows App Platform, access is denied issue

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8.1, ibm-mobilefirst

I was trying out the [Quick Start sample application](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/quick-start/cordova/) and I've encountered the following issue (see screen shot) where an "access denied" JavaScript runtime error occurs when the app tries to obtain the token from the MobileFirst Server.

I have seen similar issues too when I followed the sample application steps for Windows application.

- mfpdev version 8.0.0-2016110713
- cordova version 6.4.0
- connected to a remote MobileFirst Server hosted on Windows Server 2012.

[image]

Comment: What is your cordova-windows plug-in version?

Comment: Sorry, I am quite new at this. I used the command "cordova platform version". The installed platform is windows 4.4.3

Comment: To list all plugins use `cordova plugins list`. To remove the cordova-windows plugin use `cordova platform remove windows`. To add cordova-windows@4.2 use `cordova platform add windows@4.2`.

Comment: While cordova is installing "cordova-plugin-mfp" for windows version 4.2. It says "Plugin doesn't support this project's cordova-windows version. cordova-windows:4.2.0, failed version requirement: >=4.3.0 <5" Skipping 'cordova-plugin-mfp' for windows. Is this behavior correct?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I meant "4.4.2".

Comment: I still have the same issue. The screenshot below is taken from mfpdev app preview command via mobile browser simulator https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCW7m.png

Comment: I've forwarded this question to the development team

Comment: Am I supposed to overwrite the file mfpclient.properties? Because the JavaScript console is displaying an error message 'Failed to send native request' with the following:

Request timeout for [${wlServerProtocol}://${wlServerHost}:${wlServerPort}${wlServerContext}/apps/services/api/com.ibm.mfpstartercordova/windows/${wlServerProtocol}://${wlServerHost}:${wlServerPort}${wlServerContext}/api/registration/v1/self]

Comment: The Cordova app is updated with the server connection values after you run the `mfpdev app register` command. There is no need for a manual action on your part.

Comment: Please read: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/application-development/sdk/cordova/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the above sample with windows platform 4.4.2 it works fine. But you need to overwrite the mfp-client.properties file. Since this is a known issue on mfpclient.properties values not being updated automatically as we run 'cordova prepare' with latest cordova 6.4, and that will be fixed in next cordova-windows release.

Please try overwriting the mfp-client.properties with proper values. It should work.

Comment: It works! Thanks! This is the steps that I followed. Use the command 'mfpdev app register' first. Followed by 'cordova prepare' and then copy the contents of Project-Root/platforms/windows/mfpclient.properties and overwrite the contents of the same file generated by Visual Studio (assuming you are using it).